# Cursors in functions/procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

I would like to know if the following is possible in SQL Server - it involves **cursor usage** and I'm not sure **how** to place that inside of a function or stored procedure.

What would you recommend?

`TABLEA` has the following columns:

```
Column1, Column2
```

Example

```
Column1 Column2
------- -------
anna     a
anna     b
ben      b
john     c
john     b
john     a
```

Possible values in column2 are: a, b and c (no duplicates for a certain value on Column1)

Create `TABLEB` structure: `Column1 Column3 Column4 Column5.`

1. Have a cursor loop through all the rows of `TABLEA`
2. `SELECT * FROM TABLEB WHERE Column1 = (cursor row).Column1`
3. If no rows are returned from the previous select,
   insert a row into `TABLEB` with `Column1 = (cursor row).Column1` and NULL values on Columns3, 4 and 5.

   If (rows returned from previous select) > 0:

   {
   if TABLEB.Column3 not null, Update TABLEB with (cursor row).Column2

   else if TABLEB.Column4 not null, Update TABLEB with (cursor row).Column2

   else if TABLEB.Column5 not null, Update TABLEB with (cursor row).Column2 
   }
4. END Cursor Loop

As you see, I know very well what I want to do but little of syntax or what it's recommended in this case.

The output should be after these steps:

```
Column1 Column3 Column4 Column5
------  ------- ------- -------
anna    a        b       
ben     b            
john    c        b       a
```

I'm mostly interested if it's OK to use cursors, if so do you have any tips/tutorials for learning the syntax and do you recommend that I integrate the example into a procedure/function?

Thank you!

LATER EDIT:

podiluska, I tried using a pivot, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWB
AS SELECT [Column1], 
('Column2') AS [Source],
MAX( CASE Column2 WHEN 'a' THEN Column2 ELSE '' END ) Column3,         
MAX( CASE Column2 WHEN 'b' THEN Column2 ELSE '' END ) Column4,         
MAX( CASE Column2 WHEN 'c' THEN Column2 ELSE '' END ) Column5          
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY [Column1];
GO
```

The problem with that approach was that the output is:

```
Column1 Column3 Column4 Column5
------  ------- ------- -------
anna    a        b       
ben              b            
john    a        b       c
```

You will notice the difference from the first and desired output.

Comment: "Possible values in column2 are: a, b and c (no duplicates)" Except that your example clearly shows that there can be duplicates. I think you mean that the tuple `(Column1 Column2)` is unique.

Comment: Mark Byers: Excuse me, NO duplicates for a certain value in Column1: anna can't have c twice. In this case anna has a and b.

Comment: *What would you recommend?* - **avoid** cursors like the plague!

Comment: See edit below, re: shifted columns

Answer (score 2):

You could use a cursor, but I'd suggest using a PIVOT instead
ie:

```
 select column1, 
      case a when 0 then null else 'a' end,
      case b when 0 then null else 'b' end,
      case c when 0 then null else 'c' end
 from
      TableA as p
 pivot
      (Count(column2) for column2 in ([a],[b],[c]))
 as pt
```

If you want to shift the columns, try this...

```
 select column1,
      case when c3 is null then c4 else c3 end c3,
      case when c3 is null then c5 else c4 end c4,
      case when c3 is null then null else c5 end c5
 from
 (
 select column1,
    case when c3 is null then c4 else c3 end c3,
    case when c3 is null then c5 else case when c4 is null then c5 else c4 end end c4,
    case when c3 is null or c4 is null then null else c5 end c5
 from
 (
 select column1, 
    case a when 0 then null else 'a' end c3,
    case b when 0 then null else 'b' end c4,
    case c when 0 then null else 'c' end c5
 from
    #temp as p
 pivot
    (Count(column2) for column2 in ([a],[b],[c]))
 as pt
 ) v
 ) v2
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor at all. This is easy

```
select 
    column1,
    max(case when column2='a' then column2  end) as column1,
    max(case when column2='b' then column2  end) as column2,
    max(case when column2='c' then column2  end) as column3
from
    table
group by
    column1
```

Comment: Thanks, Madhivan, I tried that - please see the last part of my question. It's a great thing indeed **but** the issue for me with this particular approach is that each column will have only one value. I explain it in the question in the difference between "my desired output" and output from applying "pivoting".